# Cannot understand a simple example in Phased Array System Toolbox (MATLAB), regarding FREE SPACE

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, radar

I am learning about radar and signal processing. I try to run a simple code snippet provided on [Mathwork's official website](https://www.mathworks.com/help/phased/ref/phased.freespace-system-object.html)

It is just about FREE SPACE, which I think you know very well, but I am new to the topic and cannot understand the MATH behind it. For your convenience, let me put the code snippet below:

```
fs = 8e3; % sampling freq    
fop = 3e8; % operating freq
freesp = phased.FreeSpace(SampleRate=fs, OperatingFrequency=fop); % define the free space
pos1 = [40000;0;0]; % position of radar
pos2 = [300;200;50]; % position of target
vel1 = [0;0;0]; % radar is NOT moving
vel2 = [0;0;0]; % target is NOT moving
x = ones(5,1); % transmitted signal, it is just 1, 1, 1, 1, and 1
y = freesp(x,pos1,pos2,vel1,vel2); % received signal
```

Obviously, the wavelength is simply calculated as $\lambda=\frac{c}{fop}=\frac{3e8}{fop}$, and the loss is equal to $L=(4\pi R/\lambda)^2$.

The value of y is

[image: The value of y is]

Although there is an explanation that

- the first sample y(1) is zero because the signal has not yet reached the target;
- the transmitted amplitude is unity, the magnitude-squared value of the signal at the target for the third sample `y(3) = 1e-5*(0.1988 - 0.0243i)` equals the inverse of the loss $L=(4\pi R/\lambda)^2$,

I cannot understand where the second value `y(2) = 1e-5 *(0.1870 - 0.0229i)` comes from.

I am wondering how it is calculated.

Any help with mathematical explanation would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.